# iOS sessionStorage and form submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, forms

My head is about to explode. I can't get this to work the way i want, and i can't seem to find out what's wrong with it.

I have a form which i need to process with AJAX.
But before i do that, i want to save it in `window.sessionStorage`.

The functionality has to work cross-device, and i'm having trouble with iOS.

There's alot of questions around stackoverflow and google concerning this, with various fixes. But none of them seem to work for me.

I have this form:

```
<form role="form" id="searchForm" data-method="search" action="" onsubmit="return doStuff('search')" data-ajax="false">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="search" id="search" name="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="help-block"><small>Search by partnumber, suppler or free text</small></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" data-ajax="false" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Search</button>
</form>
```

Now, when the form is submitted, it runs through a function at about 200 lines, i've narrowed it down to where the code breaks.
Right here:

```
sessionStorage.last = search;
return false;
```

I
've gone from `localStorage` to `sessionStorage` in hope that, that might solve the problem, it didn't

I've tried the "right" way to set the variables with this `sessionStorage.setItem('last', 'search')`
But to no help.

The form is still being submitted regardless of what i do.
If i `return false;` BEFORE the `sessionStorage` it works fine, and stops the form.

It works fine on desktops and android, but it fails misserably on iOS devices

Debugging i've tried:

```
console.log(sessionStorage.last) returns null
console.log(typeof sessionStorage) returns object
console.log(sessionStorage.last = 'foo') returns foo
```

If you need more code / need me to try anything, please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's docs, it should work:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html

I've used localStorage without any issues, but not sessionStorage (though the docs say it should be interchangeable). You could try a try-catch block, so that the code doesn't crash, and you can get some clues. Apple mentions it could throw a QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR exception.

```
try {
    sessionStorage.setItem("last", search);
} catch (e) {
    alert("error: " + e);
}
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as being the right one.  
I found out that my boss (the one testing the site) had "accidentally" put on Private Browsing, which stops localstorage and sessionstorage to save anything.